# How to hook up the C wire from my thermostat to the air handler?

Tags: hvac

[image][image]

I already have the blue wire for the common but if anyone could tell me how to wire it to this old unit please. Could I just add it to the other yellow 24v wire from the transformer?[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine.

The gist is that a transformer has two wires with 24V between them.  The R wire goes to one, the C wire is the one which is not R.

You've got a lot of exposed bare-wire 240V power in there; *be careful*  and shut off every furnace breaker before going in there.   There is likely more than one.

Comment: Ok I will give that a try and thank you for the help.

Comment: Got it hooked up and it's working great, thanks again for the assistance.